# Unable to get user agent fron Android httpclient

Tags: android, servlets, apache-httpclient-4.x, androidhttpclient

I am using httpClient to send a request from my android app to my web server and trying to take user-agent in my servlet. But am getting 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)'. How to know this request is from android app? Kindly suggest to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for android default user agent. 
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT,System.getProperty("http.agent"));

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the default User Agent.
But you can set a custom user agent like this:

```
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Custom user agent");
```

Comment: Thanks. May i know why the device information is not set by default.